How do I systematically identify and select literature?
I want to do a content analysis on particular content published in current textbooks in my discipline specific to my country. For example, Canadian political science textbooks.
I’m not sure how to systematically identify and select the textbooks.
One article with a similar approach used best-selling textbooks in their country within a given time period, then analyzed particular content published in the textbooks for their analysis.
Is this a good approach? Or are there better metrics to determine leading textbooks specific to a discipline and country?
